# Give write access to a directory only to certain apps

Tags: android

I have an app that expects the user to buy content, and I want this content to be installed by the user by downloading payed apps that write the needed content to a directory, shared between the main app and all the present and future content apps.

Is there a way to authorize the main app and the content apps to **access in read/write** to that directory, while giving to all other generic apps **only read authorization**?

The main and the content apps share the certificate, could this be used for this job?

Comment: Have you considered encryption as a solution instead?

Comment: There's no doubt that the content will be encrypted, but it can still be deleted by an app if it has write access to that directory

Comment: I don't think you can give granular read/write access like that but let's see what everyone else says. I think you'll have to rely on encryption and downloading the content again if it's not present.